# How to disable a tip line in VS code with Rust program?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

In the screenshot shown here:

[image: vs-code-rust]

VS code automatically added a tip line showing as "1 implementation" in the Rust code between line 14 and line 15.

My question is: how can I disable this gray tip line?  and what is the official name for such tip lines inserted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html), in File | Settings | search for `Rust Analyzer > Lens: Implementations` and uncheck the box then restart VS Code.

The corresponding (boolean) JSON value is `rust-analyzer.lens.implementations`.

You can still find implementations by right clicking on the type anyway, so there's no real loss in setting it to `false`.

Comment: As of Jun 2023, you need to write `"rust-analyzer.lens.implementations.enable": false`.